# How do I output data from a script into a text file?

Tags: powershell, file-io

I am trying to get the PID/VID from the a usb device though a powershell script. The issue I keep running into, is either the output file not having the full string (gets cut off with a ...) or, a formatting error if I do "ft -Auto" then I get:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

I have tried using Add-Content, as well as Out-File but I want to have multiple commands to output to one single file, so that's also part of the issue.

Here is what I have in my script:

```
$PrinterList = Get-Content C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\Devices\printerlist.txt

Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly -FriendlyName $PrinterList | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\Devices\test.txt
```

I simply put the friendly name in the printerlist.txt file, for it to search for those devices.

What DOES work, is:

```
Add-Content -Path C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\Devices\output.txt -Value (Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly -FriendlyName $PrinterList) -PassThru
```

However, that cuts off with the ... in the text file. Any idea how I can do this? I want to have multiple of these commands to output to one single file, like a log/progress report.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you output to a plain text file instead of a structured data format i.e.: Csv ? My recommendation would be, change `| Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File ...` for `| Export-Csv yourpath.csv -NoTypeInformation`. If you insist in plain text, you need to `Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String ...`

Comment: You can control the line width of the for-display formatted output lines with `Out-File`'s `-Width` parameter, but note that unless the intent is to create a file meant for the _human observer only_, you're better off creating a _structured_ text format, such as with `Export-Csv`